# Can I assign Kivy Object id reference into Python Dict

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to python and kivy, about a week back and am coding my app.

I have a page with alot labels and textinput which i create on kivy language.

Thus i needed to add a method/function in python code so that i can control the object properties depending on which button was click.

orginally my code was this. I was able to reference to each particular object and change its text color etc etc

Python Side

```
class AccWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AccWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        acc0_user_input = ObjectProperty(None)
        acc1_user_input = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Kv side

```
<AccWindow>:
    name: "acc_window"

    acc0_user_input: acc0_user_input
    acc0_user_record: acc0_user_record
    acc1_user_input: acc1_user_input
    acc1_user_record: acc1_user_record
    acc2_user_input: acc2_user_input
    acc2_user_record: acc2_user_record
```

as there are alot of objects which i need to refer to and control from the python logic in order to control the objects properties.

i decided to change use loop in function calls to reduce the number of codes needed to type.

thus i wanted to store the object id ref in dict so that my loop can access required args to change related object properties.

i am getting this error after i change to the codes below.

python side

```
class AccWindow(Screen):
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(AccWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    user_input = {'0': ObjectProperty(None), '1': ObjectProperty(None), '2': ObjectProperty(None),
                  '3': ObjectProperty(None), '4': ObjectProperty(None), '5': ObjectProperty(None),
                  '6': ObjectProperty(None), '7': ObjectProperty(None), '8': ObjectProperty(None),
                  '9': ObjectProperty(None), '10': ObjectProperty(None), '11': ObjectProperty(None)}
```

kv side

```
<AccWindow>:
name: "acc_window"

user_input['0']: acc0_user_input
user_record['0']: acc0_user_record
```

Error

```
178: user_input['0']: acc0_user_input ... 
Invalid property name
```

am i getting anything wrong? or am i unable to store id ref into python dict?

Thankful for any reply.

Comment: this is the error

Comment: >>  178:    user_input['0']: acc0_user_input
 ...
 Invalid property name